# How to count frequencies of pathways across three columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count the frequencies of numbers across three columns of a `pandas` dataframe. An example of my data is below:

```
    0   1   2
0   2   1   2
1   0   2   0
2   0   0   2
3   0   2   2
4   1   1   0
5   2   0   2
6   2   2   2
7   2   2   1
8   0   1   2
9   0   0   2
```

I want to count the frequency of particular co-occurrences of numbers. E.g. I want my final output to look like this:

```
0 1 2 freq
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 2 2
0 1 0 0
...
2 2 2 1
```

I've tried to use `pd.melt` to no success. Here is code to reconstruct my problem:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,3, 10)
b = np.random.randint(0,3, 10)
c = np.random.randint(0,3, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c]).T
```

If anybody has any tips that would be much appreciated!

Comment: And how do you define these particular coocurrences?

Comment: I count a co-occurence as `0 0 2` from my example dataframe and so increment the frequency column by 1 each time I come across that, for routes that aren't in my dataframe (e.g. `1 0 0`) I would like to assign 0 to the frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from itertools import product

np.random.seed(42)

a = np.random.randint(0, 3, 10)
b = np.random.randint(0, 3, 10)
c = np.random.randint(0, 3, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame([a, b, c]).T
columns = ['start', 'middle', 'end']
df.columns = columns

result = df.groupby(columns).size()
result = result.reindex(product([0, 1, 2], repeat=3)).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
result.columns = [0, 1, 2, 'freq']

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
    0  1  2  freq
0   0  0  0     1
1   0  0  1     0
2   0  0  2     0
3   0  1  0     1
4   0  1  1     0
5   0  1  2     0
6   0  2  0     1
7   0  2  1     0
8   0  2  2     0
9   1  0  0     0
10  1  0  1     0
11  1  0  2     0
12  1  1  0     0
13  1  1  1     0
14  1  1  2     1
15  1  2  0     0
16  1  2  1     0
17  1  2  2     0
18  2  0  0     0
19  2  0  1     1
20  2  0  2     0
21  2  1  0     1
22  2  1  1     0
23  2  1  2     2
24  2  2  0     1
25  2  2  1     1
26  2  2  2     0
```

Note that this output was produced for the following `df`:

```
   0  1  2
0  2  2  0
1  0  2  0
2  2  0  1
3  2  2  1
4  0  1  0
5  0  0  0
6  2  1  0
7  1  1  2
8  2  1  2
9  2  1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't give you the combinations that don't show up (you can use `reindex` or similar if necessary), but you can use `pivot_tables` with `aggfunc` set to `np.sum` to generate them. You'll need to add a `frequency` columns of `1` so `pivot_table` has something to add:

```
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(0,3, 10)
b = np.random.randint(0,3, 10)
c = np.random.randint(0,3, 10)

df=pd.DataFrame([a, b, c]).T
df['frequency'] = 1

df.pivot_table(index=[0, 1, 2], values='frequency', aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    0  1  2  frequency
0   0  0  0          1
1   0  1  1          3
2   0  1  2          1
3   0  2  0          4
4   0  2  2          1
...
13  2  0  2          2
14  2  1  2          1
15  2  2  0          1
```